# Magic calendar, date doesn't match the day using JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

The problem with this calendar that, in the  current month the date match with the day, but when you go back for example one month you will find that the date doesn't match the day.

This is the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/muQmX/1/).

Example August 1, 2013 is a Thursday, but this calendar show me a Friday..

A screenshot showing the problem
[image]

**Code :**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".calender").magiCalender();
});
```

Comment: Looks like a bug in MagiCalendar; I'd report it to them.

Comment: This looks like a question for the developer(s) of MagiCalendar

Comment: I think it's because they put "Sunday" as the last column, instead of the first

Comment: @lan: but the current month is good, the problem just happens with the previous months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem : **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/muQmX/2/)**

Code :

```
if(tMonth < month){
    mod = 5 - mod;
}
```